# How to change text by script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity project with a text field and I want to change it to something else by clicking a button.
Like javscript ids.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `yourText.text = "XYZ";` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here in Unity, you have a component-oriented design. Text and Button are just Components of GameObject entities. Most parts of your game scripts are also Components that are attached to GameObject. This is a core concept you'd need to realize when you come from JS.

In short, to change a text by clicking the button you need:

```
1) Create a GameObject with a Text component;
2) Create a GameObject with a Button component;
3) Create a GameObject with a component of your custom script;
4) Create the reference in your custom script on the Text component you want to update;
5) Create a public method in your custom script that will be invoked when you click Button;
6) Assign that method invocation to the OnClick button event through Unity inspector.
```

Your script will look like this:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] 
        private Text _title;

        public void OnButtonClick()
        {
            _title.text = "Your new text is here";
        }
    }
```

Your scene should look like this. Pay attention to the highlighted Title reference. You need just to drag-n-drop Title GameObject here, and that's it.

[image: a]

Select your button, assign a GameObject with your script and select a public method that needs to be invoked

[image: a]

Welcome in Unity and happy coding!

Comment: WOW!

This was exactly what I needed! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 9):

Unity recently added [TextMeshPro](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html) in version 2021.3 as a way to display text. This process is much the same, but the only thing is to include "using TMPro" (instead of UnityEngine.UI) and "TMP_Text" (instead of "Text"). The updated code would look something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private TMP_Text _title;

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        _title.text = "Your new text is here";
    }
}
```

Comment: You *really* have to wait until you can comment. This amends a small part of the accepted answer, but is not an answer in itself.

Comment: True, but even though my reputation is too low to comment, I also think that the people viewing this answer need to know. Would you by any chance mind commenting this answer for me (w/ or w/o credit)? Or is it considered better to take it down and comment when able? Thanks.

Comment: As for 2022, this answer worked best for me. I was having issues assigning the Text gameobject to the slot because of a type mismatch. It was because now it seems like Unity uses TMP_Text and not Text types anymore.